# Adjustment of Border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want a border of Div to be less than the width of div. How to implement that in CSS?

Following image will give you more Clarity:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/divkr.jpg/

Comment: Not possible. You'll need a second element

Comment: is not possible! but an alternative solution is create an image and put it as background... only if you don't want to add other element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with plain CSS.

You could however use two div's to get this effect.

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">

    text

</div>
</div>​

.outer
{
    background-color:blue;
padding:20px;
    width:200px;
}

.inner
{
    border:solid 1px white;
    height:150px;
    color:white;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/RreTH/

http://jsfiddle.net/RreTH/1/

Answer (score 2):

### That is not possible.

Border is always the outside of element's box model. However there might be a workaround you would like.

```
<div>
   <div id="inner" style="border:5px #000 solid;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, in this example, the border of #inner, will never exceed that of the parent.

As for the demonstration part, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/vWWkL/).

You will notice, the outer div has a thin red line to mark its border, but the inner div's border can act as `outer` `div`'s inner border.

Hope it helps